# Kendo Datasource updating remote data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What am I doing wrong? I have a kendo datasource setup as such

```
var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read:
                {
                    url: "/Home/ReadStarkArea",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            update:
                {
                    url: "/Home/UpdateStarkArea",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            destroy:
                {
                    url: "/Home/DeleteStarkArea/",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        id: { type: "number", editable: false },
                        ZipCode: { type: "string" },
                        CarrierRoute: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: sharedDataSource,
        autoBind: true,
        selectable: true,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "ZipCode", title: "Zipcode" },
            { field: "CarrierRoute", title: "Carrier Route" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }],
        editable: "popup"
    });
```

the URL's defined in the transport all point to methods in my controller. The read works fine but neither the update or destroy call the their methods. Furthermore, once I get the update and delete calling the correct methods, how do I know what data needs updating? does the transport pass a param with the changes?

Comment: The grid sends the updated object as Json to your controller. Your ASP.NET MVC action should take an object of a type that can be deserialized from the receive Json. The default model binder will handle the rest. As for your update not happening, did you add the [HttpPost] attribute on your Update controller action? It the acction getting called at all? Have you checked the Json sent by your grid? What have you tried...?

Comment: My controller action isn't getting called at all for the update or destroy. It only gets called for the read.  I have some mock data in the controller's read method and that data gets sent to the kendo datasource just fine. I have a breakpoint set in my controller's update method. but that breakpoint never gets hit when I attempt to modify the values in the grid. Also, I do have the [HttpPost] attribute on the controller action. I have added this to my datasource and the only alert msg i get is "Read"

parameterMap: function (options, operation) 
{
   alert(operation);
}

Comment: Look at the Json sent by the grid. If you use Chrome, look at the Network tab in the Dev Tools. If not, get Fiddler or something similar.

Comment: ok my controller code is finally getting called. The JSON looks good on the client side (just before it is sent to the controller [{"Id":4,"ZipCode":"30731","CarrierRoute":"1"}] ) but the parm value passed to the controller is empty. It's not null but the values are empty. I have the param type as object. I tried the actual type too and the fields (Id, zipcode, etc..) were all empty in the param.

Comment: First, it won't work with object. Keep in mind that JSON is just a big string. It doesn't have any information about the type. When the action receive the request, it checks all the Json sent with it and figures out how to fit it in the model. If it's not defined, he doesn't know what to construct. I don't know what a dynamic would do (I'm actually curious at this point). I believe you can also put a FormCollection parameter on the action and you will have the complete form in there. But in the end, you should use the Model. [...] Post too long.

Comment: Now the reason why those values are empty and not null is because when your action figures out you are receiving data, it will instantiate the Model and start filling it. It failed to find any properties on the Model so now you have to figure out why by looking at the received data versus your model (In your action, take a look at `Request.Form`). By looking at your answer, your Json seems to be an array of your model (it is wrapped in brakets). Perhaps you can put IEnumerable<YourModel> as your parameter. There is also a [Bind] attribute you can put on your attribute for special cases.

Comment: Also, I'm unsure why it would be an array. Kendo's grid only send an array with the update when it's set to Batch updates / deletes which is not your case.

Comment: I set batch to true. that's why the json contained an array - sorry. I removed the parameterMap function and now it works fine.  Thanks for all of your help.